# Nesting array.some() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering about nested uses of Array.some(). Suppose the task is to determine whether three numbers in an array sum to a given value x. I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
return myArray.some(function(num1){
    myArray.some(function(num2){
       myArray.some(function(num3){
           return num1 + num2 + num3 === x;
       });
    });
 });
```

Any insight on this would be helpful, including why the above doesn't work.

Comment: while you take all the same array, you may add the same value tree times, is it what you want, or is it just a bad example of an other problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return the response of each nested `myArray.some` otherwise, the enclosing method will receive an undefined.

See the code below.

```js
var myArray = [1, 3, 7, 21];
var x = 31;

var opt = myArray.some(function(num1) {
  return myArray.some(function(num2) {
    return myArray.some(function(num3) {
      return num1 + num2 + num3 === x;
    });
  });
});

console.log(opt);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) then you can omit return if only one statement:

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the
>   explicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit
>   return statement.

So this should work:

```
myArray.some(num1 =>
  myArray.some(num2 =>
    myArray.some(num3 => 
        num1 + num2 + num3 === x;
    )));
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not return the inner result to the outer callbacks.

```
return myArray.some(function(num1) {
    return myArray.some(function(num2) {
        return myArray.some(function(num3) {
            return num1 + num2 + num3 === x;
        });
    });
});
```

If you like to prevent adding same values from same indices, you could add a check, which allowes only values which are not at the same index.

```
return myArray.some(function(num1, i) {
    return myArray.some(function(num2, j) {
        return myArray.some(function(num3, k) {
            return i !== j && i !== k && num1 + num2 + num3 === x;
        });
    });
});
```